# Find a point on the line and a vector parallel to the line.

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the given equation of a line to find a point on the line and a vector parallel to the line.

$x(t)=(1-t)(4,6)+t(-2,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x(t)=(1-t)(4,6)+t(-2,0),$ which has the equivalent form

$\begin{align*}
(1-t)(4,6)+t(-2,0)&=(4-4t-2t,6-6t)\\
        &=(4-6t,6-6t)\\
\end{align*}
$

So a vector parallel to this is $\frac{d}{dt}(4-6t,6-6t)=(-6,-6).$

For any time $t,$ the equation $(4-6t,6-6t)$ describes a point on the line. So take $t=0,$ then $(4,6)$ is on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can put any value of $t$ (e.g. 0, 1) to obtain points on the line.

Choose any two points and do the subtraction you will have the direction vector.

Comment: The _op_ already has two points $(4,6)$ and $(-2,0)$. The direction vector is the normalized of the difference of these two point.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see that $$\begin{align} x(t=0) & = (4,6) \\ x(t=1) & = (-2,0) \end{align} $$

Both of these points belong to the line. All points $x(t)$ belong to the line.

The direction is found by the difference between these two points.

$$ (-2,0) - (4,6) = (-6,-6) $$

The unit direction vector is thus $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ or $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. Either one is correct unless some other convention is specified.